# Tengo un bean en mi configuración pero no lo reconoce. Java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring

Puse las anotaciones correctas y he intentado no utilizar lombok, pero aún así no funciona. Este es el eror:

```
Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'dev.gabyy.Moovies.MovieRepository' in your configuration.
```

Este es mi maín:

```
package dev.gabyy.Moovies;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class MooviesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MooviesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Mi interfaz que es la que "Falta"**

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends MongoRepository<Movie, ObjectId> {
}
```

**Aquí implemento la interfaz**

```
@Service
public class MovieService {
    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository repository;
    public List<Movie> allMovies() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Obviamente tiene sus respectivas importaciones. He intentado hacer sus getters y setters y constructor para no usar lombok pero igual no me sirve. Ví que se puede solucionar con @Service pero necesito que sea @Repository. Estoy usando IntelliJ IDEA y Springboot 3.1.9

Comment: Podrías compartir el código del archivo MongoConfig o como lo tengas implementado el método algo así como esto: @Override public Collection getMappingBasePackages() { return Collections.singleton("dev.gabyy.Moovies"); }

Comment: Hola! Te dejo mi repositorio! https://github.com/GabyyHshss/MoviesAPI

Comment: Gente lo solucioné volviendo a crear el proyecto verificando paso por paso cada ejecución. Hice una instalación limpia. Saludos